# CODEIGNITER, Reference data from 2 tables to show in view file

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

Trying to cross reference data from 2 tables and only show the data from 1 of the tables...

If a "district" in table 001 matches a "district" in table 002 then I'd like to echo the corresponding "coordinator" from table 002

**TABLE 001**

```
|  month_of_report  |  district  |    org     |  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|      January      |   004     |    Dallas  |
|      February     |   029     |    Dallas  |
|      March        |   047     |    Dallas  |
```

**TABLE 002**

```
|  coordinator  |  district  |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|      Jamie    |   004      |
|      Susie    |   047      |
|      Jimmy    |   029      |
```

**MODEL**

```
    public function reg_co()
    {
        $this->db->where('report_month', $report_month);
        $query = $this->db->get('non_clinical_total_tests');

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('coordinator');
        $this->db->join('non_clinical_total_tests', 'non_clinical_total_tests.district = coordinator.district');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->row();
        }

    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
          $data['reg_co'] = $this->Page_model->reg_co();
```

**VIEW FILE**

```
            <?php if($reg_co) : ?>
                  <strong>DISTRICT: </strong><?php echo $reg_co->district; ?><br>
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

If the district from the 2 tables match then I should be able to echo the coordinator for that district.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
________________________________________________________________________________
//This code is for single record from database

//Model function
public function reg_co()
{

    $this->db->select('non_clinical_total_tests.*');
    $this->db->from('non_clinical_total_tests');
    $this->db->join('coordinator', 'coordinator.district = non_clinical_total_tests.district');
    $this->db->where('non_clinical_total_tests.report_month', $report_month);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    if($this->db->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $this->db->get()->row();
    }
    return false;
}

//View file

<?php if($reg_co) : ?>
    <strong>DISTRICT: </strong><?php echo $reg_co->district; ?><br>



_____________________________________________________________________________________

//This code is for all records from database

//Model function
public function reg_co()
{

    $this->db->select('non_clinical_total_tests.*');
    $this->db->from('non_clinical_total_tests');
    $this->db->join('coordinator', 'coordinator.district = non_clinical_total_tests.district');
    $this->db->where('non_clinical_total_tests.report_month', $report_month);
    if($this->db->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
    return false;
}

//View file

<?php if($reg_co) : ?>
    <?php foreach($reg_co as $reg) { ?>
        <strong>DISTRICT: </strong><?php echo $reg['district']; ?><br>
    <?php } ?>
```